# Managing ERC-20 tokens in a corporate setting

Tags: wallets, erc-20, multisignature

What are my options for managing large quantities ERC-20 tokens in a more corporate manner. In particular multi-sig and disaster recovery. I like the features in Mist/EW, but do these multi-sig and withdrawl limits work for tokens too?

Answer (score 2):

Just be aware of the fact that this is early technology. We have some standards and a bit of software but are vastly lacking best practices, tools that are suited for noon-technical users and corporate processes.

That being said you want to probably defend yourself against hacks and malicious employees. The former requires hardware wallets like [Digital Bitbox](https://digitalbitbox.com), [Ledger Nano S](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/products/ledger-nano-s)
or [Trezor](https://trezor.io) which are orders of magnitude harder to attack or infiltrate than e.g. a corporate Windows laptop. The latter requires multi signature accounts like [this one] (https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet) which requires e.g. 3 of 5 parties to sign a transaction.

A combination of hardware wallets with multi signature wallets is thus likely a good starting point. Managing backups of the keys on individual basis, who is a signer on the first place and other question need to be addressed by every organisation for now, I'm not aware of proven industry standards - there likely aren't any as this whole field is barely 2 old and you probably know how slow leaving curves of corporate processes evolve.

Comment: Thanks for the sensible response. I'm pretty sure that the sort of features for tokens that I'm seeking will exist in software wallets long before hw-ones.

Comment: Just beware that software wallets are never more secure than the OS - which in most corporate settings should be considered infiltrated by default.

Comment: lol, yes, there is more that goes into securing a wallet than the selection of the wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Any functionality that there is for transfer of ethers can almost always be replicated in a token's contract code.  Withdrawal limits, time limits, multisig requirements are all possible, just has to be written in the contract code.

Basically the way the code for tokens works is that you can literally encode all of the usual corporate governance rules.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Mist/EW already have these features? I'm not looking to create my own smart contract, I'm looking to use a product that is proven.